# ngrok tunnels to localhost reconnecting issue

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, live-streaming, tunnel, ngrok

I have a camera set up on my ARM based system running ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS. I am accessing internet from an ethernet cable of my modem. I am able to view the live stream from my camera using motion software on my local network. However to view these streams from the internet, I found this software ngrok. After installation, when I type

```
./ngrok http 80
```

or

```
./ngrok tcp 22
```

or anything else, it says connecting initally but then, goes to

```
Tunnel Status                 reconnecting (x509: certificate has expired or is
```

How do I resolve this ?

Other information which might be useful:

```
Version                       2.0.19/
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: `sudo ngrok -log=stdout 80` to see the problem

Comment: ngrok http --region=eu 3000 helped

Answer (score 7):

I have sometimes the same issue. I have found, that when the ngrok can not connect, the browser can the site https://ngrok.com open, but in the console the command:

```
ping ngrok.com
```

returns: 'Request timeout'.

In my case is the problem in VPN. When I terminate the VPN, then I can connect to ngrok. And the ngrok continues to work after I log in to the VPN again.

Comment: try `ngrok http -region=eu {port_number}`

Comment: cant not ping ngrok.com but cant visit https://ngrok.com

Answer (score 6):

**Please disconnect and reconnect your wifi connection. For me it worked**

Comment: Same for me. It works

Answer (score 4):

Could you access the website though? Like try to access https://ngrok.com using any browser and see. If it does not work, then maybe the portal is blocked by your internet!

Answer (score -3):

You could use other tunnel solution.

Please have a look

> https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/

Please follow these steps to use new way to create tunnel from localhost

```
website: `https://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/`
1) run
=> curl -s https://pagekite.net/pk/ |sudo bash
2) Signup
=> pagekite.py --signup
3) Completed all the details
4) pagekite.py 3000 yourname.pagekite.me
Ex:
pagekite.py 80 vijaychouhan.pagekite.me

MORE
```

To remove pagekite account

pagekite.py --remove vijaychouhan.pagekite.me

```
if your pagekite account is expired then signup on pagekite.me with new email and get new account.
once you will signup successfully with new account then you can get Default Kite Secret into account tag.

now goto home folder and find .pagekite.rc file and replace your
kitename   = NEW PAGE KITE
kitesecret = SECRET KEY

Enjoy with new account
```